# How to distinguish between incomplete jsons and invalid jsons in JSONDecoder from python's json library

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
decoder=json.JSONDecoder()
print(decoder.raw_decode('[[['))
Result: ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

print(decoder.raw_decode(']['))
Result: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Is there any way for me to distinguish between an error, raised due to an incomplete json versus an error due to an invalid json? (There are also variations of the error messages of both types such that I can't distinguish them based on the error message)

Comment: Isn't incomplete just a type of invalid?

Comment: Right, but I want to distinguish them

Comment: To what end? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm reading json from a buffer, so I need to determine if I should wait for the user to complete the json or exit due to an error